# Python Regex for alpha(alpha|digit)*

Tags: python, regex, lexical-analysis

I'm trying to produce a python regex to represent identifiers for a lexical analyzer.  My approach is:

```
([a-zA-Z]([a-zA-Z]|\d)*)
```

When I use this in:

```
regex = re.compile("\s*([a-zA-Z]([a-zA-Z]|\d)*)")
regex.findall(line)
```

It doesn't produce a list of identifiers like it should.  Have I built the expression incorrectly?

What's a good way to represent the form:

```
alpha(alpha|digit)*
```

With the python re module?

Comment: Your regex is fine, but some tips: you should prefix your regex string with an `r` to make it a raw string literal. Also, you shouldn't use capturing groups unless you have to, if you need to use bracketing just use the `(?:...)` syntax.

Comment: try [regex101](https://regex101.com/#python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this:

```
regex = re.compile(r'[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\d]*')
```

Note the r before the quote to obtain a raw string, otherwise you need to escape all backslashes.

Since the `\s*` before is optional, you can remove it, like capture groups.

If you want to ensure that the match isn't preceded by a digit, you can write it like this with a negative lookbehind `(?<!...)`:

```
regex = re.compile(r'(?:^|(?<![\da-zA-Z]))[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\d]*')
```

Note that with `re.compile` you can use the case insensitive option:

```
regex = re.compile(r'(?:^|(?<![\da-z]))[a-z][a-z\d]*', re.I)
```